# How to render choice fields one by one

Tags: forms, symfony, radio-button, twig

How can I render choice fields using one by one with Twig?

I have this field for generating radio buttons :

```
...
->add('types', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        'c1' => '1',
                        'c2' => '2',
                        'c3' => '3',
                        'c4' => '4'
                    ),
...
```

and this make radio buttons, but I want to render one by one because the radio buttons are all inline...

With Twig I render with: `{{ form_widget(form.types) }}` or `{{ form_row(form.types) }}`, but make the same...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can render them one by one with this in your Twig :

```
{% for type in form.types %}
    {{ form_row(type) }}
{% endfor %}
```

You can even divide the rendering (as [explained in the doc here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-each-field-by-hand)) to adapt it to what you want :

```
{% for type in form.types %}
    {{ form_label(type) }}
    {{ form_widget(type) }}
    {{ form_errors(type) }}
{% endfor %}
```

After that, you just have to see what's generated, and adapt your code to include new lines where you need it.

Comment: sorry I delete, only a thing, for define so: {% for... % } it's all, thanks ! :)

Comment: Good catch! Edited, clad it had helped you ;)